# Implement security to qGIS Server (for windows)

Tags: qgis-server, security

I have few map services running on QGIS Server(v 2.2.X on Windows 7 32 bit) and anyone can connect or access those services (WMS & WFS).

Is there any way to implement security in QGIS Server? So that I can set, assign username & password to those map services.

I researched on my side and following [few links](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Authentication-in-QGIS-Server-WFS-Service-td5080742.html) in which provides few steps such as apply password to specific folder, creating .htaccess file, also researched official site of QGIS Server but cannot find any valid document.

Any help will be great!!! Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If so, could you post it here as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelUnderwood  unfortunately not..still looking on my side

Comment: any luck yet? Same problem here...